# Scanf missed line

Tags: scanf

I wrote a test program which should take in a 3x3 matrix of characters and output the entered matrix. However, I have to enter 4 lines in order for the program to produce the corresponding matrix. I have looked up problems on the scanf function, but none of the solutions I tried seemed to work...Could you help me out with this?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

 int main(void) {


     char a[3][3];
     int i,j;

     for(i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
        }
        scanf("\n");
     }

     for(i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            printf("%c",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

     system("PAUSE");

     return(0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c",...)` get the whitespaces and the `\n`. You can solve it in many ways:

If you read like `a b c`

```
for(i=0;i<3;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
            cin.get(); //Get the spaces after each character and the \n at the end of each line
        }
    }
```

or you can simple use `cin` (read char/string inputs with scanf is always a problem)

```
 for(i=0;i<3;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
```

if you are reading like `abc`, you only have to substitute your `scanf("\n")` for a `cin.get()`

Answer (score 0):

@João Menighin's answer surely works. If you want to avoid c++, this would work:

```
for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
   for(j=0;j<3;++j)
   {
       scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Although it would ignore ALL whitespace: both `abc` and `a b c` would be interpreted to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a white space in your scanf right after the "

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
```

I had the same problem in a two-dimension matrix and it worked for me.
I have no idea why though!!! I just spent 1 hour in front of my laptop trying different things...

Answer (score 0):

Have tried your and IT WORKED.  Although, I did make a few changes per comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // added, but that shouldn't matter
main()
{
     char a[3][3];
     int i,j;

     for(i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
        }
        //scanf("\n"); // not necessary, see below
     }

     for(i=0;i<3;++i)
     {
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
        {
            printf(" %c",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
     }

     return(0);

}
```

Compiled and ran this code on Eclipse/Microsoft C Compiler and entered series of characters followed by enter.

```
abcdefghi
 a b c
 d e f
 g h i
```

The point of confusion might be that `scanf` pulls the data from a console buffer.  Typically, (although you can work around this) that buffer is returned to your program when you press enter.  Also, the format specifier of `%c` also accepts blanks.  Thus, I tried a second run with the following input and output.

```
a b c d e 
 a   b
   c  
 d   e
```

You can tell the spaces were read and stored as well as the letters.

Hope this helps.